# connecting sortable lists disallowing sorting on the first list jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I don't know if this is possible but I want to do a few things,

I have 2 sortable lists that are connected. I don't want to sort the first list, but I need the items to be able to be dragged into the 2nd list.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#webappsearchresults12267, #portfolio-ul" ).sortable({
            helper: 'clone',
            connectWith: ".connect",
            scroll: false,
            tolerance: 'intersect',
        stop: function(){
            var order = $("#portfolio-ul").sortable('toArray');
            $("#CAT_Custom_196863").val(order);
        }

        })
    });

<ul id="#webappsearchresults12267>
<li>item-1</li>
<li>item-2</li>
<li>item-3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="#portfolio-ul">
<li>item-4</li>
<li>item-5</li>
<li>item-6</li>
</ul>
```

I have also an option for cloning the item I pick up from the first list...
"helper: 'clone'," doesn't appear to be working for me,

Anyone any ideas? I might not be looking at a sortable list solution but rather drag and drop.. with a sortable list for the 2nd list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remove '#' from your IDs in HTML, next use IDs for LI items to get some data when 'toArray' called. I posted working example:

HTML:

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li id="ul_item_1">item-1</li>
    <li id="ul_item_2">item-2</li>
    <li id="ul_item_3">item-3</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<ul id="list2">
    <li id="ul_item_4">item-4</li>
    <li id="ul_item_5">item-5</li>
    <li id="ul_item_6">item-6</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$( "#list1" ).sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    connectWith: "#list2",
    scroll: false,
    tolerance: 'intersect',
stop: function(){
    var order = $("#list2").sortable('toArray');
    alert( order );
}

}).disableSelection();

$( "#list2" ).sortable().disableSelection();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/4XAXR/3/

Comment: legend! this is what I'm after, sorry i didn't mean to add # to the id's i had to write the lists because in my eg they are dynamic

Comment: Is there any way to drag from list 2 to list 1 again?

Comment: Sure! Just add propper config to $( "#list2" ).sortable().disableSelection(); eg $( "#list2" ).sortable( {connectWith: "#list1", <and all configs and callbacks that you need> } ).disableSelection();

Comment: awesome, i think this is going to work well, I have one question though, I kinda wanted the list 1 items to be unsortable in list 1 and also to be able to select more than one item at a time and drag it into list 2... I know im a pain lol

Comment: Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/FAmk6/1/ But I don't have time now to find the way to drag multiple elements from list 1 to list 2, sorry... I just got married)))

Comment: wow congrats ! ! ! I'll take a look at this code, GET OFF THE COMPUTER AND ENJOY YOURSELF! lol

Comment: if it's not clear from @CoolEsh example the trick is to use http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable to link up draggables to sortables.