# Control click or shift click multiple items and drag them

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have been looking on these forums all day and tried lots of plug-ins namely  : jquery.hotkeys.js and the http://thechriswalker.net/select-drag/ example here complete with an excellent plug-in, it's just a lot more complex than what I think I'm looking for.

I already have a drag and drop situation with sortable in list 2 thanks for to CoolEsh for his amazing help earlier on.. [connecting sortable lists disallowing sorting on the first list jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324330/connecting-sortable-lists-disallowing-sorting-on-the-first-list-jquery)

So now I'm needing a control click to select more than one and drag it across. But I don't want loads of mark-up and jQuery. but I also don't want to use a complex plug-in like the ones I mentioned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The event `e` has built in variables that you can access for checking if <kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> have been pressed. Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```
$('#selectableitems p').click(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) alert('control pressed');
    if(e.altKey) alert('alt pressed');
});
```

If you know that control is also pressed, you could add a class `selectedItem` or something like that. On a mouseup event you could check if the key is pressed and delete the `selectedItem` class if not. Than just add a draggable to the `$('.selectedItem')` and you're pretty much there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take a look at this later, but excellent job :)

Comment: anytime! I'm glad i could be of help

Comment: Perfect!! works a dream, what i need now is to add the draggable to the .selected class!.